# Python Decrease dbf Index Time

Tags: python-3.x, indexing, dbf

Attempting to decrease the time it takes to index a dfb file. I am using the following to create an index:

```
bid_index=table.create_index(lambda rec: rec.bidid)
```

This works but seems to take very long time. I have not actually timed the process time, but I can count seconds until the process returns a result. The index returns approx 40,000 plus records. Just wondering if there is a faster way to search dbf for a particular value.
If there is no way to speed up the indexing, anyway to break once the value is found while the indexing is taking place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `dbf` is a pure-Python program.  This means there are no low-level routines to speed up certain actions.  In order to create an index every single record is scanned to build the key.  This is only beneficial if you are going to do at least a couple searches.  If you are only doing one search with that type of key, just scan with a `for` loop.

Comment: Yes , I believe you are correct in using a for loop in my case. I am only searching for a single value one time. The for loop probably will be better than making the index and searching.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a custom index implementation to speedup index creation.
There is a huge performance diff on my use case for a 100.000 lines file with 20 columns:

- 10s with library implementation
- 0.13s with custom implementation

```
class CustomIndex:
    """
    non-persistent index for a table, for unique str column field_name
    """

    def __init__(self, table: dbf.Table, field_name, codepage):
        self._table = table
        self._recnum_by_val = {}

        # read whole file
        nb_rows = len(table)
        tmp = table._Table(nb_rows, table._meta)
        tmp._meta.dfd.seek(0)
        content = tmp._meta.dfd.read()
        memview = memoryview(content)

        meta = tmp._meta
        header = meta.header
        size = header.record_length

        fielddef = meta[field_name]
        self._key_size = fielddef[dbf.Field.LENGTH]
        field_start = fielddef[dbf.Field.START]
        field_end = fielddef[dbf.Field.END]
        
        # read field value
        location = header.start
        for i in range(nb_rows):
            record_data = memview[location + field_start:location + field_end]
            value = str(record_data, codepage)
            self._recnum_by_val[value] = i
            location += size

    def search(self, val):
        recnum = self._recnum_by_val.get(val.ljust(self._key_size, ' '))
        if recnum is not None:
            record = self._table[recnum]
            return [record]
        else:
            return []


table = dbf.Table(filename='test.dbf', codepage='utf8')
with table:
    index = CustomIndex(table, 'NAME', 'utf8')
    # index = table.create_index(lambda rec: (rec.NAME))
    
    for vals in [{'NAME': 'toto', 'VAL': 1}, {'NAME': 'tata', 'VAL': 2}]:
        match = index.search(vals['NAME'])
        # match = index.search(vals['NAME'].ljust(70, ' '))
        if len(match) > 0:
            dbf.write(match[0], **vals)
        else:
            table.append(vals)
```